# El método toString me produce NullPointerException

Tags: java

Me aparecen los siguientes errores en este programa y no se donde está el fallo.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at examen2.Ciudadano.toString(Ciudadano.java:20)
>   at examen2.Principal.main(Principal.java:8)

Este es mi código:

```
public class Persona {
    String nombre;
    char sexo;

    public Persona() {
        sexo='F';
    }

    public void setPersona(String nombre,char sexo){
        this.nombre=nombre;
        this.sexo=sexo;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return " Nombre:" + nombre + " Sexo:" + sexo ;
    }
}       

import java.util.Scanner;
public class Ciudadano {
    Persona per1;
    int dni;

    public Ciudadano() {
        dni=0;
    }

    public void setCiudadano(int dni){
        per1 =new Persona();
        Scanner sc=new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Escribir nombre y sexo de persona(M,F)");
        per1.setPersona(sc.nextLine(),sc.next().charAt(0));
        this.dni=dni;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return per1.toString() + " DNI " + dni;
    }
}

public class Principal {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Ciudadano p1=new Ciudadano();
        Ciudadano p2=new Ciudadano();

        System.out.println(p1.toString() + p2.toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

modifiqué tu código `setCiudadano(int dni)` a esto:

```
public void setCiudadano(int dni){
                per1 =new Persona();
                Scanner sc=new Scanner (System.in);
                System.out.println("Escribir nombre y sexo de persona(M,F)");
//esto puede quedar igual a como lo tenías e igual funciona, pero para mejor entendimiento te lo dejo así.
                String nombre = sc.nextLine();
                char sexo = sc.nextLine().charAt(0);

                per1.setPersona(nombre, sexo);
                this.dni=dni;
            }
```

en tu `main` lo modifiqué a esto:

```
public class Principal {
            public static void main(String[] args) {

                Ciudadano p1=new Ciudadano();
                Ciudadano p2=new Ciudadano();

                p1.setCiudadano(1);
                p2.setCiudadano(2);

                System.out.println(p1.toString());
                System.out.println(p2.toString());

            }
}
```

y al correrlo funcionó así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema radíca en que en `SetCiudadano` tiene declarado *int dni* y al quererlo correr, no has declarado nada. En tu `system.out.printl(p1.toString()+p2.toString())` debe mostrar los datos ya, lo que ya ha ingresado, y te estás saltando eso, antes de meterlo en un `system.out.println();`, debes hacer las operaciones o las instrucciones que quieres hacer. Y luego mostrar ya el resultado.

Comment: Esa no es la raíz del problema. La raíz es que el atributo `Persona per1` es nulo, por ende al ejecutar `Ciudadano#toString` y ejecutar `per1.toString()` lanza el NPE porque `per1` es nulo. Una solución es llamar al método `setCiudadano(<algún valor>)` como propones, pero esto **no evitará** que si no se invoque `Ciudadano#setCiudadano` se siga lanzando el NPE. La solución correcta es corregir el método `toString` para que soporte el caso en que `per1` es nulo.

Answer (score 1):

Fijate que hasta que no hagas por ejemplo

```
p1.setCiudadano(2000000)
```

no se va a inicializar persona dentro de la clase ciudadano, y cuando quieras imprimir sus datos, directamente no van a existir.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando haces una instancia de `Cuidadano`, el miembro per1 (clase `Persona`) es Null. Solo se le asigna una referencia al momento de invocar al metodo `setCiudadano`. Lo más recomendable en mi concepto sería realizar una instancia de per1 en el constructor de `Ciudadano` en lugar de hacerla en el metodo `setCiudadano`.

```
public Ciudadano() {
  per1 = new Persona();
  dni=0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Debes de hacer esto:

```
p1.setCiudadano(20);
```

Ya que la clase Ciudadano tiene la variable per1 de tipo Persona la cuál se inicializa en el método setCiudadano. Cuándo haces lo siguiente: `p1=new Ciudadano()` la variable per1 está `null` por eso te marca ese error en el System.

Yo te recomendaría que usaras Herencia, ya que dentro de POO no queda del todo correcto que un `Ciudadano` tenga una `Persona`.

Answer (score 0):

El error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   examen2.Ciudadano.toString(Ciudadano.java:20) at
>   examen2.Principal.main(Principal.java:8)

se obtiene ya que la variable  `per1` tiene un valor null, para evitar esto, antes de llamar el método:

```
public String toString(){
    return per1.toString() + " DNI " + dni;
}
```

debes de llamar el método `setCiudadano()` para inicializar `per1` :

```
  public void setCiudadano(int dni){
        per1 =new Persona();
        Scanner sc=new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Escribir nombre y sexo de persona(M,F)");
        per1.setPersona(sc.nextLine(),sc.next().charAt(0));
        this.dni=dni;
    }
```